# Mission to educate?

Tags: sources-mekorot, gentiles, chinuch-education

Someone told me that Jewish people have, loosely speaking, a mission to be educators by  teaching others sciences, religion etc. Are there any sources to back this up? Preferably some quotes?

Comment: Sounds interesting. If you don't mind my asking, who'd you hear this from? Was this person a rabbi? I ask because [the more information you provide about your assumptions, the stronger your question is](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3683/5323)/the more likely it is you'll get high-quality answers.

Comment: It's possible that this might have something to do with [Torah Umadda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torah_Umadda)

Comment: It was a person.I wish I could ask him now, but I lost contact with him.

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/59266. And less similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35695

Comment: Is this possibly related to the Jewish people being a "light unto the nations". This concept requires Jews to set an example of ethical, legal and moral behave to all peoples.

Answer (score -2):

The children of Israel will be great sages and spread the light of Torah. The entire world will be occupied with knowing God. The children of Israel should teach the seven laws of the children of Noah to the children of Noah.

> "And he said, It is a light thing that thou shouldest be my servant to
> raise up the tribes of Jacob, and to restore the preserved of Israel:
> I will also give thee for a light to the Gentiles, that thou mayest be
> my salvation unto the end of the earth." - *Isaiah 49:6*

Israel will be a light to goyim - haShem's salvation for goyim.

> "NUN. Thy word is a lamp unto my feet, and a light unto my path." -
> *Psalm 119:105*

Torah is a light.

> Moses only gave the Torah and mitzvot as an inheritance to Israel, as Deuteronomy 33:4 states: 'The Torah... is the inheritance of the congregation of Jacob,' and to all those who desire to convert from among the other nations, as Numbers 15:15 states 'the convert shall be the same as you.' However, someone who does not desire to accept Torah and mitzvot, should not be forced to.
>
> By the same regard, **Moses was commanded by the Almighty to compel all the inhabitants of the world to accept the commandments given to Noah's descendants.**
>
> If one does not accept these commands, he should be executed. A person who formally accepts these commands is called a resident alien. This applies in any place. This acceptance must be made in the presence of three Torah scholars.
>
> Anyone who agrees to circumcise himself and allows twelve months to pass without circumcising himself is considered as one of the nations. - *Hilchot Melachim 8:10*

Israel will teach the world Torah, which for goyim are the seven laws of the children of Noah.

> In that era, there will be neither famine or war, envy or competition for good will flow in abundance and all the delights will be freely available as dust. **The occupation of the entire world will be solely to know God.**
>
> Therefore, the **Jews will be great sages** and know the hidden matters, grasping the knowledge of their Creator according to the full extent of human potential, as Isaiah 11:9 states: 'The world will be filled with the knowledge of God as the waters cover the ocean bed." - *Hilchot Melachim 12:5*

All of creation will be involved in the knowledge of God and Israel will be great sages.